# Count positive values in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an elegant way to count how many values are positive in a datatable without having to go through every element and check it? I've looked at DataTable.Compute method and some LINQ examples too but they all require a column name and I need it for the whole table.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole table"? Do you want to check the values in ALL columns of the table?

Comment: Do you understand that the table probably also contains some 'technical' columns like primary/foreign keys that usually are also numbers and their "sign" is meaningless?

Comment: I couldn't imagine any scenario where this would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

No need (for the code) to know the column names :

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row1 => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                   .ToDictionary(column => column.ColumnName, column => row1[column.ColumnName]))
                 .SelectMany(f=>f.Values)
                 .Count(f=>decimal.Parse(f.ToString())>0);
```

Example :

6 positive :

[image]

Comment: @quetzalcoatl 1) he said _without_ knowing their names....no ? 2) Also - there is **no way** without iterating through all elements.

Comment: I've removed all my comments, because I've just noticed that the question was about "DataTable" not a "data table", so it's all about in-memory ops not querying the database. I somehow misread that. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DataTable.Select?

```
int TotalPositiveValues = 0;
foreach (DataColumn NextColumn in MyDataTable.Columns)
{
    DataRow[] PositiveRows = MyDataTable.Select(NextColumn.ColumnName + " >=0");
    int TotalPositiveValues += PositiveRows.Length;
}
```

**EDIT:** provided all values in your DataTable qualify as numbers.